# Send attachments on mail from S3 bucket using Java

Tags: java

I want to send attachments (files from S3 bucket) in a mail triggered to users. How can be this done using Java?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried though.
If file size greater then I would suggest to create presigned URL for files and share them via mail.
If files are too short in size, better to go with download and attach.
reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Comment: thanks for the response, but we can drop the presigned URL as the files are not greater than a MB.